# JQuery .addClass doesnt add the classes or create elements as coded and gives no errors

Tags: jquery, openlayers

I am trying to add toggle functionality to the openlayers layer switcher layers using Jquery addclass and accordion. But i am unable to find the error as the classes are not being added on document ready. I am new to JQuery and openlayers and cannot understand the mistake I am making.
I am able to view the map in the center layout and the layer switcher in west pane. But my accordion, my plusminus symbol, toggle effects , addClass are not working.
Any comments anyone...?

```js
var map;
  function init() {

     map = new OpenLayers.Map({
         div: "mapPanel",

         numZoomLevels:31,
         controls:[]
     });


     var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
         'OpenStreetMap Layer'
        );
     var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('OpenLayers WMS',                 'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
     {layers: 'basic'},
     {});
    
     map.addLayers([osm,wms]);
 
     map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
      map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({
      div: document.getElementById('layer_switcher_control')}));
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();

  }

$(document).ready(function () {
 $('body').layout({ applyDemoStyles: true }); 

   $(".baseLbl,.dataLbl").addClass("accordion_head").append('<span class="plusminus">'+"+"+'</span>');
  $(".baseLayersDiv,.dataLayersDiv").addClass("accordion_body").css({"display":"none"});
  $( ".olButton" ).wrapAll( "<p class='p_inputs' />");
 


  //toggle the component with class accordion_body
  $(".accordion_head").click(function() {
        if ($('.accordion_body').is(':visible')) {
            $(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
            $(".plusminus").text('+');
          }
        if ($(this).next(".accordion_body").is(':visible')) {
              $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
             $(this).children(".plusminus").text('+');
         } else {
         $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideDown(300);
         $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');
      }
  });
});
```

```css
#layout-west {

 background-color: #333 !important; 
 padding: 5px !important;
}

#layer_switcher_control {
   border:1px solid #fff;
   padding:2px;
 }

#layer_switcher_control .baseLbl {
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
  padding: 7px 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

#layer_switcher_control .baseLayersDiv .labelSpan {
font-family: Georgia;
font-variant: small-caps;
}

#layer_switcher_control .baseLayersDiv {
   background: #888888;
   padding-top: 5px;
   color: white;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}


.plusminus {
  float: right;
}
 

 a{
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      label{
  cursor:pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-layout/1.4.3/layout-default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-layout/1.4.3/jquery.layout.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.12/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<body onload="init(); ">
 
    <div id = "layout-west" class="ui-layout-west">
   <div id="layer_switcher_control" class="accordion_container"></div><!--layer switcher-->
 </div>
 
 <div class="ui-layout-center">
  <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="mapPanel"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you create a *minimal* snippet that demonstrates your issue?  eg in your code you use `$(".baselbl")` but there's no `baselbl` in your html.  If this is added eg by openlayers later, then it's probably just a case that your code is running too soon.  Add `console.log($(".baselbl").length)` to your doc ready to see if it's available at that time.

Comment: Yes this class of div is added by Openlayers. I too think the object is not created by the time I am trying to add a class to it. So in that case ,how do I assure that my object is created and then I am adding my classes.
Also, I need the plusminus symbol to appear on right side of the Base Map label as soon as the page loads. How can I load these differently?

Comment: and on checking console.log($(".baselbl").length)... I get a 0 in return.

Comment: A rudimentary scan of the docs (http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/index.html) suggests that you could use the render event `ol.render.Event`

Comment: I included the jquery code after the code for map rendering. Then I was able to solve the problem. Thanks again for you help.